# Set permission for creating nodes in code

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Can I set permissions to allow authenticated users to add nodes of a custom type? I need to do that in module i'm trying to create. As I can see hook_permission it's actually just for creating new permissions.

Comment: No need to use code, just go to Admin -> People -> Permissions and set the appropriate permissions there

Comment: But what if I wan't all setting I need to be installed when I'm activating module?

Comment: Ah fair enough, you can use [`hook_node_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7)

Comment: Maybe I don't get it but isn't $account parameter for user ID? I need to use anonymous and authenticated roles.

Comment: Traditionally in Drupal you would create a permission, then assign that to the roles you're interested in. Then in `hook_node_access()` you would use `user_access('custom permission', $account)` to determine access for the node/given account. You could always just check `$account->roles` for the role(s) you're interested in, but that's not considered best practice

Comment: I should have read the comment -.-"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your module name is say mymodule, then defien a your "create node" permission in hook_permission. Then implement hook_node_access to check and return permission for the content type you have implemented.

SAMPLE CODE.
NB: It won't work out of the box, you got to replace your module name, permission name and the content type name to get it to work. And don't forget to clear your cache, TWICE!.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_permission().
 *
 */
function mymodule_permission() {
  // define your add permission.
  // Naming of "array key" is important. We use that later.
  return array(
    'YOUR CONTENT NAME: add' => array(
    'title' => t('Add Project Management Team'),
    ),
   );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_access().
 */
function mymodule_node_access($node, $op, $account = NULL) {
  $type = is_string($node) ? $node : $node->type;
  // make sure you are responding to content type defined by your module only.
  if ($type == 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_NAME_HERE') {
    // If no account is specified, assume that the check is against the current logged in user
    if (is_null($account)) {
      global $user;
      $account = $user;
    }
    if ($op == 'create' AND user_access('YOUR CONTENT NAME: add', $account)) {
      return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
    }
  }
  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```

References:

[hook_permission()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7).
[hook_node_access()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7).